# Django post_save not getting many-to-many attributes on create

Tags: python, django

I am binding a `post_save` method to a model in django, like the following code:

```
def save_mymodel(sender,instance,*args,**kwargs):
    print 'save called'
    for parameter in instance.parameters.all():
        print parameter.name

post_save.connect(save_mymodel, sender=MyModel)
```

Here are my models:

```
def MyModel(models.Model):
    parameters = models.ManyToManyField(Parameter)

def Parameter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

When I try create a `MyModel` from django admin with any number of parameters, I only get `save called` as output. If I save the same `MyModel` object again from the admin, all the parameters are printed. What is the difference between calling `save` on create and not on create? How can I make sure I get all the attributes of a model using `post_save` on its creation?

Comment: Try `m2m_changed.connect(save_mymodel, sender=MyModel.parameters.through)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ManyToMany` fields do not participate in model `save()` method, so `post_save` would not recognize any m2m changes. To detect m2m change, use `m2m_changed` signal.

[django doc about m2m_changed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed).

Comment: Shouldn't `m2m_changed` be called on create? I changed my code from `post_save` to `m2m_changed`, but the function is not even called on creation this way

Comment: No it's a separate signal. But you don't add `m2m` field on `save()` anyway, right?

Comment: Is there a way to get the m2m attributes and make some operations with them when I create the object using django admin?

Comment: Why can't you use `m2m_changed`? The signal will be triggered when you save m2m.

Comment: It doesn't trigger when I create the object from the admin. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure from admin side because I never tried it. Sounds like there are bug reports from django but got fixed in late versions. Which version are you using?

Comment: Nevermind, I was passing the wrong sender. It should be `MyModel.attributes.through`